# Get current database connection in Visual Studio extension

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, data-connections, server-explorer

I'm trying to write an extension for Visual Studio (2019) which will add new Intellisense capabilities when writing SQL queries.

I have found an example on how to extend the text editor and show suggestions. But in order for the suggestions to be meaningful, I would like to get the connection to the database used in that query window:

[image]

And then use it to create those suggestions.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Copil tempel, did you find solution for this issue ? I am stuck with same task, no documentation is found on this.

Comment: No, I've abandoned this project a while ago.